# How to lock DATAAARA by C API as400

Tags: c, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

How to lock DATAARA by MI using C API? The lock()/unlock() function only for userspace objects.

The QXXRTVDA() — Retrieve Data Area function is only show information without locking.

The cmd system("ALCOBJ MYDAXXX *DTAARA"); is no wait if dataara already locking from  another job.

The current code (is not good)

```
while(  system("ALCOBJ MYDAXXX *DTAARA ") != 0) {sleep(1);}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use lock() MI function, that provides a wait_time argument, defined in QSYSINC/MIH/LOCK. You maybe want to wrap QXXRTVDA() and lock() functions into your own function. Use unlock() to do the reverse.
All MI functions are thoroughly described in "ILE C/C++ for AS/400 MI Library Reference, SC09-2418-00" released for V3R7, that's the current book version since November 1996.
In that book you'll find useful examples as usual.

Comment: I can't  to use the lock()/unlock() function, it can to use  only for userspace objects, not for DTAARA.

Comment: @AlexandreKalendarev I don't think so. To get the system pointer required by lock() api, you should use rslvsp() api with WLI_DTAARA as object type argument, member of _OBJ_TYPE_T enum defined in mih/micommon.h, that's included by #include <milib.h>. The complete list of object types is defined in mih/miobjtyp.h

Comment: I have error:  Object domain or storage protection error for offset  in object DATEST.  Application error.  MCH6801 unmonitored by QC2UTIL1 at statement        
   0000000012, instruction X'0000'.

Comment: code is:  some_object = rslvsp( WLI_DTAARA, "DATEST", "MYLIB", _AUTH_ALL );
 mitime( &timeout, hours, minutes, seconds, hundredths );
 lock( some_object, timeout, _LENR_LOCK );

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a wait time for ALCOBJ. The wait time is specified in seconds.

```
ALCOBJ OBJ((MYDAXXX *DTAARA *EXCLRD)) WAIT(60)
```

Comment: It works for me. What is the return code from the call to system()? I get a return code of 0 if the data area exists and it could get the lock, and a return code of 1 if the data area does not exist or if it could not get the lock. There is no message in the joblog because system() removes the message. If another job has the lock, my program waits.

Comment: Thanks Barbara, I  wrote: ALCOBJ OBJ((MYDAXXX *DTAARA *EXCL)) WAIT(60) without RD

Comment: *EXCL also works for me. What do you mean that it doesn't work? Is the data area not getting locked? Or is it not preventing another job from getting the lock?